# Как сделать алиас команды в модуле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

Допустим у меня есть файл test.py

```
def example():
    print("some text")
```

И в питоне я пишу

```
import test
test.example()
```

И код работает как надо, но как заменить `test.example()` на `example()`?
(Т.е. создать команду без указания модуля, как например в turtle вместо `turtle.left()` можно написать просто `left()`)

Answer (score 1):

Подключить определённые объекты модуля можно с помощью инструкции `from`. Она имеет несколько форматов:

```
from <Название модуля> import <Объект>
from <Название модуля> import <Объект> as <Псевдоним>
from <Название модуля> import * # Импортирует все объекты из модуля
```

При данном подходе вы сможете обращаться к импортируемым объектам без указания модуля.

Answer (score 1):

используйте `from ... import ...`:

```
from example import example1, example2
```

Но так достанется только некоторые значение, можно достать все:

```
from example import*
```